# C program crash after first scanf

Tags: c, scanf, realloc

This function is causing my program to crash:

```
void input_data(int** data, int* data_size)
{
    int i;
    char c;

    //input with error handling
    do
    {
        printf("Write, how many integers you want to input: ");
    }
    while (((scanf("%d%c", data_size, &c) != 2 || c != '\n') && clear_stdin()));

    //memory reallocation
    *data = (int *) realloc(*data, *data_size * sizeof(**data));

    printf("\nInput %d integers\n", *data_size);

    for (i = 0; i < *data_size; i++)
    {
        while ((scanf("%d%c", data[i], &c) != 2 || c != '\n') && clear_stdin());
    }
}
```

In my main() I got

```
int* numbers = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(*numbers));
int input_size;
input_data(&numbers, &input_size);
```

My program crashes after first integer input, and I believe this is caused by scanf, but I can't realize why.
If you need, I can provide full source code of my program.

Comment: Consider sharing the stack trace!

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", data[i], &c)` --> `scanf("%d%c", &(*data)[i], &c)` or `scanf("%d%c", *data + i, &c)`

Comment: "I can provide full source code of my program" - yes, please - a link to ideone or other online compiler with that code included would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't doing what you expect:

```
scanf("%d%c", data[i], &c)
```

`data[i]` is not the address of the `i`'th element of the array.  This expression translates to `*(data + i)`.  This expression is actually treating `data` as an array of `int *`, but `data` is a pointer to a `int *` variable, so this leads to undefined behavior.

You want to first dereference `data`, then get the array element.  So the expression you want is `(*data + i)`, or equivalently `&((*data)[i])`.